# Downloaded MailMergePro file seems to have virus attached

Tags: virus, antivirus, scan

I downloaded MailMerge Pro from `http://www.standss.com/emailmerge/download_process.asp` website and i scanned it on VirusTotal.com and two of the antivirus flagged it.
I am sharing the link for same, i am not sure if this actual virus or it is a false flag

https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/ba37e35beeb8d28c2a3ca7b99201159f24672ac0181d4cfa0b6fd5754cb46592/analysis/1506994938/

Is it safe to use or not?

Answer (score 2):

I would exercise caution here, although this could be a false-positive, considering that a lot of the other scanners on the site didn't pick anything up.

`TR/Dropper.MSIL.Gen`, according to [Avira's website](https://www.avira.com/en/support-threats-summary/tid/7697/threat/TR.Dropper.MSIL.Gen), is a generic name for specific Trojans that Avira detects that are currently not specifically named.

In this case, I would run this in a virtual machine or on a test machine that doesn't have physical access to your main computer. Install the program, then run a full system scan with various virus/malware scanners, such as Malwarebytes, ESET, Avast, etc..

I rarely recommend this, but you could also try downloading it from other reputable download sites, although your download experience may vary.